# Sending a value to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, anchor

Need your help again. I am trying to create a payroll system for a friend of mine and I am stuck with this line of code.

```
<table border=6 cellpadding=10 cellspacing=0>
    <tr align=center valign=middle>
        <td>Employee ID</td>
        <td>13th Month</td>
        <td>Date Updated</td>
        <td>Options</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("db_payroll");
        $payroll_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_payroll");
        while ($payroll = mysql_fetch_array($payroll_sql))
        {
    ?>

        <tr align=center valign=middle>
            <td><?=$payroll['emp_id']?></td>
            <td><input type=checkbox name="13thmonth" value="<?=$payroll['emp_id']?>"></td>
            <td><?=$payroll['datesaved']?></td>
            <td><a href=generate_payroll.php?id=<?=$payroll['emp_id']?>>Generate Payroll</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Actually, this code is running without errors but I wonder how can I send the value of the checkbox to the other page specified by the anchor tag("`generate_payroll.php?id=...`")

How will I do this? Any answer related to this question is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Input tag need a `form tag` to get its value post to action page.

Comment: Apart from the missing quotes on your link, is it not being displayed as expected?

Comment: Use form tag first of all. then the next thing

Comment: @Rikesh Yes, it needs form tag but I don't wanna use button but instead an anchor tag.

Comment: @Fluffeh upon clicking the link, I was redirected to the page which is what is supposed to occur but I wanna the checkbox value be sent to the page as well.

Comment: @PratikJoshi I tried adding the form tag and the submit button too but it would redirect me to the page anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You need a form first of all...

```
<form id='myForm' action='generate_payroll.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name=id value='<?php echo $payroll['emp_id']?;>'>
<tr align=center valign=middle>
        <td><?=$payroll['emp_id']?></td>
        <td><input type=checkbox name="13thmonth" value="<?=$payroll['emp_id']?>"></td>
        <td><?=$payroll['datesaved']?></td>
        <td><a href='#' class='nextPage'>Generate Payroll</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </form>
```

Store you $payroll['emp_id'] in a hidden field.

And wire up some jquery so you dont have to have a button for Generate Payroll/

```
   $('.nextPage').click(function(){
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
```

Then on your generate_payroll.php page, simply retrieve...

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $month = $_POST['13thmonth'];
```

Or whatever you wanna do with the POST results

Of course if you dont care about having a button, you can bypass jquery altogether and just do...

```
 <form id='myForm' action='generate_payroll.php' method='POST'>
 <input type='hidden' name=id value='<?php echo $payroll['emp_id']?;>'>
 <tr align=center valign=middle>
    <td><?=$payroll['emp_id']?></td>
    <td><input type=checkbox name="13thmonth" value="<?=$payroll['emp_id']?>"></td>
    <td><?=$payroll['datesaved']?></td>
    <td><input type='submit' value='Generate Payroll'></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

for assigning value to `id` you are using `?id=<?=$payroll['emp_id']?>` as per me you have to code like this :

```
?id=<? echo $payroll['emp_id']?>
```

Try following code and check if URL looks as you want.

```
 <tr align=center valign=middle>
        <td><?php echo $payroll['emp_id']?></td>
        <td><input type=checkbox name="13thmonth" value="<?php echo $payroll['emp_id']?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $payroll['datesaved']?></td>
        <td><a href="generate_payroll.php?id= <?php echo $payroll['emp_id']?>">Generate Payroll</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```